# Storing objects of different derived classes of an abstract base class in an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class

I am a  complete beginner trying to learn C++. So, this question might sound very cliche` . Please help me understand where I am going wrong.

The problem is described below.

### Objective :

1. Define an abstract class Shape to act as interface. (Use pure virtual functions)
2. Override the methods in the derived classes Rectangle, Circle, Triangle.
3. Two functions are needed - a. read() -> To read input parameters(measurements) of a particular shape.
                               b. area() -> To calculate the total area of a shape.
4. Store objects(or pointers to objects) of different derived classes in an array.
5. Calculate area of each array member.
6. Calculate total area.

### Code Snippets :

*shape.hpp* - Base class header file.

```
namespace generalShape
{
 class Shape { 
     public :          
         virtual void read() = 0;
         virtual double area() = 0 ;         
 };
}
```

*rect.hpp* - Derived class header file.

```
namespace rect2D
{
 class Rectangle {
     private :
         double length;
         double breadth;

     public :
         void read();
         double area() ;           
 };
}
```

Similar header files are also written for two other derived classes,
namely *circle.hpp* and *triangle.hpp*

*rect.cpp* - Derived class implementation file.

```
using namespace rect2D;

// Read data (use it in main.cpp)
void Rectangle::read(/* no args */)
{   
 std::cin >>  length;  
 std::cin >>  breadth;
}

// To calculate area of a rectangle object
double Rectangle::area(/* no args */)
{ 
 return length * breadth;   
}
```

Similar implementation files are also written for two other derived classes,
namely *circle.cpp* and *triangle.cpp*

*main.cpp* - Client file.

```
using namespace generalShape;
using namespace rect2D;
// similarly use other namespaces as required

int main()
{
 int number_of_shapes; // take input from user about number of objects
 double total_area = 0;

 /* Method 1 */
 Shape **arr;
 arr = new Shape*[size];

 /* Method 2 */
 //vector<Shape *> arr;

 for (int i = 0; i < number_of_shapes; i++)
 {
     // some code to ask user about type of object

     if (choice == 1)//based on user input
     {
         arr[i] = new Rectangle();       // for method 1
         //arr.push_back(new Rectangle); // for method 2
     }

     // similar code for other derived class object types

     // Code to calculate total_area of all objects in array.
     arr[i]->read();
     total_area += arr[i]->area();
 }
 return 0;
}
```

### What is my Problem?

In main.cpp, I have specified *Method 1* and *Method 2* as comment lines in the main function.

**Method 1** tries to use an **array of base class pointers to point to derived class objects** of different classes ( that's allowed, right ?). But it is giving an error.
`error: cannot convert ‘rect2D::Rectangle*’ to ‘generalShape::Shape*’ in assignment`and similar errors for other derived class objects.

So, I tried to typecast my way around the problem.

```
// Shape is the base class with virtual methods read() and area().
// Rectangle,Triangle,Circle are derived classes which override these methods.
// main.cpp uses these header files to read user input using read() for each 
// derived class and then calculate area using area(). The ultimate goal is to 
// calculate total area of all derived class objects stored in an array.

arr[i] = (Shape*)(new Rectangle()) ;
```

Doing this, allows compilation without error. But when I try to execute, it gives segmentation fault. I am not sure about why this is happening. But I think it is because I  defined pure virtual functions in the base class header file. Even if that is the case, I am not sure as to how to correct it.

Secondly, in **Method 2**, I tried to use **vectors** to achieve similar functionality after looking through other suggestions on stackoverflow. But now I am getting an error.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<generalShape::Shape*>::push_back(rect2D::Rectangle*)’
             arr.push_back(new Rectangle);
                                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/vector:64:0,
                 from src/main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:939:7: note: candidate: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = generalShape::Shape*;
_Alloc = std::allocator<generalShape::Shape*>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = generalShape::Shape*]
       push_back(const value_type& __x)
       ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:939:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘rect2D::Rectangle*’ to ‘generalShape::Shape* const&’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:953:7: note: candidate: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = generalShape::Shape*; _Alloc = std::allocator<generalShape::Shape*>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = generalShape::Shape*]
       push_back(value_type&& __x)
       ^~~~~~~~~
```

And I cannot understand how to correct this. So, I am stuck on this problem and am not able to solve it.Please help me to understand and correct the errors.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't link to external places where we must go for references to your questions. This is a Q&A site, and every question must be self contained, with a proper [mcve]. Since you are new, I recommend you take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [ask] questions befitting of this format.

Comment: Okay. I will edit my question to include the code after taking the tour. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: If you have two classes, `B` (being the base class) and `C` (being the child class that inherits from `B`), then a pointer to `C` doesn't need to be casted with `B*`. In fact, any kind of C-style casting is a red flag that probably means you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, I thought so too. I was just trying that to see, if the program compiles when I do that. Because, if it did, that would mean, I am definitely making a mistake somewhere. And, it did compile. So, I became sure that I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just forgot to specify, that your class rect2D::Rectangle implements your abstract interface class generalShape::Shape.

You can do this by adding

> : public generalShape::Shape

to the declaration of rect2D::Rectangle.
The fixed declaration is then:

```
namespace rect2D
{
 class Rectangle : public generalShape::Shape {
     private :
         double length;
         double breadth;

     public :
         void read();
         double area() ;
 };
}
```

One more hint: Please define a virtual destructor in your base class generalShape::Shape, if you intend to destroy your objects via the container holding the base class pointers.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That indeed was a very bad case of overseeing on my part.